# FileUtils.copyFile() not creating file when destination is a network path (on windows)

Tags: java, windows, apache-commons-io

I'm using apache common's [FileUtils.copyFile()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile(java.io.File,%20java.io.File)) to copy a file on a local disk to a network share location. The shared folder already exists, and the user running the app has permission to it. FileUtils.copyFile() executes with no exceptions. However, the file doesn't actually get created.

```
File sourceFile = new File ("C:\\sourcefile.txt");
File destinationFile = new File("\\data-server\\my_share\\dest.txt");
// false
System.out.println("Before copy, file exists? " + destinationFile.exists());
FileUtils.copyFile(sourceFile, destinationFile);
// true
System.out.println("After copy, file exists? " + destinationFile.exists());
```

With the network share path specified as the destination, it doesn't work. But, if I map the network drive in windows and write to it via the network map, it works. What's very odd is that I call file.exists() after the copy operation, and java reports that the file exists, but it doesn't show up.

I also tried using FIleUtils.copyFileToDirectory(), just specifying the destination directory and not the file name. I'm getting the same issue when the destination is the network path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your destination needs additional escape characters.

```
"\\\\data-server\\my_share\\dest.txt"
```

Comment: This is correct. However, I'm still really confused why it was being reported that the file was created.

Comment: It was likely created at the root of the current drive.  Look for it under c:\data-server\my_share\dest.txt

Comment: Yes, just found that. You are correct. Well, that was exciting!