# Issue saving to Windows "mapped network drive" in Electron

Tags: javascript, windows, electron

I have an Electron app in early beta and we just got a report that it is not saving correctly to a *"DOCUMENTS directory that is using folder redirection to a network location"*. The user is in a large, IT-managed computing environment.

I work on `macOS` and only use `Windows` under emulation to test and debug simple issues, nothing involving networking and I don't know how to handle this.

This is a "presentation tool" type app where the user can "import" (copy) media assets to a project folder, sequence them and save that sequence for later presentation. The typical steps would be, after user launches app and opts to create a new project:

1. user is presented with a `showSaveDialog` to select where the
   project should be saved. The default path specified in the dialog
   options is `app.getPath('documents')`. **The path returned by that dialog is used for all subsequent copying and saving operations**
2. the project folder is
   created along with several subfolders for asset types
3. a `JSON` file is created at the top level of the project folder and as the
   user selects media assets on their hard drive (using `showOpenDialog`), those assets   are copied over to the project

---

**Comments from the user:**

> Creating a project does not save when saving to the windows DOCUMENTS
>   directory that is using folder redirection to a network location. If
>   you save as, then the .json file is created. Asset directorys are not
>   created when starting a new project in the DOCUMENTS directory (that
>   is using folder redirection to a network location).
>
> Saving directly to a mapped drive does work as expected.

---

> I was cleaning out my system drive and found the location where the
>   app was storing the files. Instead of saving in the specified network
>   location it was generating the same folder structure in the root of
>   the C: drive.   So instead of the files being saved
>   to \Server\Username they were being saved to C:\Server\username

---

Is this some issue with Electron's [app.getPath('documents')](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetpathname) function? The only manipulation I do to this user-specified project path is to convert it to a `UNIX` style path using [upath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/upath) in order to make the paths crossplatform compatible.

```
let projectPath = upath.toUnix(directoryPath);
```

> **[upath.toUnix(path)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/upath#upathtounixpath)**
>
> Just converts all `` to / and consolidates duplicates, without
>   performing any normalization.

Could this be stripping out a critical part of the path of a networked drive? Perhaps I should also/instead be using:

> [**upath.normalizeSafe(path)**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/upath#upathnormalizesafepath)
>
> Exactly like path.normalize(path), but it keeps the first meaningful
>   ./.
>
> Note that the unix / is returned everywhere, so windows \ is always
>   converted to unix /.

---

Sorry this question is so long but it seems such an odd issue and I don't have an easy means to debug it. If you have read this far, do you see any obvious cause for the issue? I saw this question ([FileUtils.copyFile() not creating file when destination is a network path (on windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518487/fileutils-copyfile-not-creating-file-when-destination-is-a-network-path-on-wi)and) maybe it is related? I am just baffled by all the Windows slashes and escaped slashes. . .