# Is this an error in the "path.normalize" documentation?

Tags: node.js, path

I've trying to figure out an issue with file paths using [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) and [upath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/upath#upathnormalizesafepath)
*(specific question: [Issue saving to Windows "mapped network drive" in Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60355123/issue-saving-to-windows-mapped-network-drive-in-electron))*

Reading the documentation for [path.normalize(path)](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_path) it gives the following examples:

> **For example, on POSIX:**
>
> path.normalize('/foo/bar//baz/asdf/quux/..');
>    // Returns:
>   '/foo/bar/baz/asdf'
>
> **On Windows:**
>
> path.normalize('C:\temp\\foo\bar\..\');
>   // Returns: 'C:\temp\foo\'

In the first example, what happened to "quux"? And in the second, what happened to "bar"? Are these just copy-paste errors? Sorry if this seems a trivial question but this "path" stuff, particularly on Windows, is very confusing to me (I'm on macOS).

Comment: This is expected because of the `..` at the end that goes up one level.

Comment: @jfriend00 - thanks for the reply. Why (and how), in "the real world", would one end up with a path which contains a directive at the end to go up one level? It's rather baffling to me.

Comment: It's not usually used at the end.  More commonly used at the beginning of a path relative to the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Like the doc says:

```
The path.normalize() method normalizes the given path, resolving '..' and '.' segments.
```

Try without the `..` at the end, that is suggesting that you're going one directory up and is getting interpreted as basically

```sh
cd /foo/bar//baz/asdf/quux
cd ..
```

Also, this might be a mistake but you got two slashes between `bar//baz` in here.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I just copied the examples from the docs.